# Охальник и подхалим: родственные ли слова?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Охальник - это, как я понимаю, человек, который кощунствует, сквернословит или просто ведет себя неподобающе. Часто это слово употребляют просто как ругательное.
При этом оно мне кажется родственным слову "подхалим", которое также несет негативную окраску, но смысл его в чем-то даже противоположный: если охальник ведет себя нагло, то подхалим, наоборот, угождает и подлизывается.
Родственны ли эти слова и, если да, то почему? Очень было бы интересно узнать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этимологическом словаре Крылова говорится :

> **ПОДХАЛИМ**
> Это слово, имеющее значение "льстец, угодник", восходит к той же основе, что и существительное нахал.

Объяснение короткое и непонятное. Слово *нахал* что означает?
В Словаре 1847 слова *подхалим* еще нет, но есть *халуй* :

> **Халуй**, простонародное.
> 1) Презрительное название слуги, холоп.
> 2) Человек грубый, наглый, имеющий халуйские ухватки.

Сравниваем с *нахалом* :

> **Нахал** - наглец, бесстыдник.

Очевидно, есть связь у *нахала* с *халуем* по смыслу, значению корня. Посмотрим в Словаре 1789-94, в каком гнезде расположили *нахала* его составители.

> **Хайло**, низкое слово.
> 1) Горло, кадык.
> 2) Грубиян, горлан.
> **Хайлю** - кричу громко, нагло.
> **Нахальный, нахайливый** - наглый, бесстыдный.

Подведем итог. *Охальник* - родич нахала, бесстыдный грубиян. *Подхалим* - мелкий ("под"), но наглый и бесстыдный льстец, прислужник, угождатель своих хозяев, *халуй*. 
В основе всех разбираемых слов лежит   **хайло** (горло, кадык). Оно, в свою очередь, происходит от *хай* - крик, шум, скандал.

Дополнительный материал.
Подхалим.
Словарь Даля :

> **Подхалюза**
>
> м. новг. перм. ряз. пролаз, ловкий пройдоха; лукавый, скрытный и льстивый.
>
> Подхалузник м. подхалузница ж. влгд. бродяга, шатун;
> || новг. льстец, подлипала.
> || Кур. неопрятный.
>
> Подхалим или подхалима м. твер. костр. перм. льстивый попрошайка, пролаз, плут и лукавец.

Фамилия *Подхалюзин* использована Островским в пьесе "Свои люди - сочтемся", для персонажа пройдохи-приказчика.

Холюза - донское слово, означает угодливого, льстивого человека.

Answer (score 2):

У Черных и Шанского к одной группе относятся самые различные по значению  слова с корнем ХОЛ: холуй, холоп, нахал, охальник, подхалим, холить, холостой/холощеный, также шалить. В них выделяется и.-е. корень (s)kel со значением резать, стричь, отделять.Соответственно, приходится решать,  что общего у этих слов.

Группа 1.

ХОЛИТЬ (ухаживать, мыть, подстригать); ХОЛОП - стриженый мальчик, потом слуга; ХОЛУЙ - холоп, который ухаживает, холит хозяев; ПОДХАЛИМ - похожий на холопа/холуя.

Группа 2. ХОЛОСТОЙ/ХОЛОЩЕНЫЙ - отрезанный, опустошенный, отделенный.

Группа 3. НАХАЛ, ОХАЛЬНИК, ШАЛИТЬ/ШАЛЕТЬ -  наглый, вызывающий, высокомерный. Значение вторичное: ведущий себя неправильно. Сравнить: кричит как резаный, также: резвый от резать.

ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ

Отдельно рассматривается глагол "хаять", который  связывается с "каять", но при этом отмечается влияние диал. "хайло" - устье печи, также горло, пасть.

ВЫВОД

Охальник и подхалим, сточки зрения этимологии, являются однокоренными, хотя обозначают совершенно разные свойства характера.

Слово "подхалим" по значению близко к "холить", и.-е. ksol -скрести, драить, чистить, мыть , ухаживать.

Слово "охальник" ближе к словам "шалый, шальной, ошалеть", ср. диал. "хальный" - нахальный.